# How to Glusterfs reload the gluster volume/bricks info

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm2, glusterfs

I have setup GlusterFS (3.5.3) replicated volumes on top of LVM on two identical Ubuntu 14.04 servers(vmware workstation). they are working fine.i want to know how to reload the gluster brick/volume information on gluster server/client when the Logical volume is increased equally on both servers to scale out the Glusterfs. heres my output for gluster volume info

```
root@gluster2:/storage# gluster volume info all
Volume Name: gvola
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: fca40349-5fc6-4974-a7b7-a2f3d560f41b
Status: Started
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: gluster1:/public/sdb1/brick
Brick2: gluster2:/public/sdb1/brick

root@gluster1:/storage# lvs
LV      VG        Attr      LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%   Convert
root    ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---   18.74g                                           
swap_1  ubuntu-vg -wi-ao--- 1020.00m                                           
lvmhome vg10      -wi-ao---    3.99g
```

Answer (score 1):

If your glusterfs bricks reside on LVM logical volumes, then you should be able to simply resize the LV and the filesystem on it, and the gluster clients should see the new larger size immediately without any gluster-specific steps required.  Assuming "lvmhome" in your example is the LV being used for the bricks, and you want to grow it by 2GB, you should be able to do this by running "lvextend --resizefs --size +2G /dev/vg10/lvmhome".  This is a non-destructive operation, and you can do this while the filesystem is online and in use.  Once you've run this on both of the gluster servers, the clients should see the new larger gluster volume.

Comment: Thanks   @Paul Stauffer. I tried with lvextend but used xfsgrowfs since the FS was xfs underneath but still the gluster info showed older info and I cannot copy/create files according to added disk in lvm(i also restarted the VirtualMachines but still same size of glustervolume). since I was just testing ,i used individual disks with equal size on both VM's like /sda1 and added /sdb1 later to glustervolume which allowed me to increase glustervolume. I have not tried  gluster on top of lvm on version > 3.5.3 and  3.6 and 3.7 though